# Search Form In Rails Application Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to implement some search functionality in application and it will be on all the pages of the application. I have put the following code in my /layout/application.html.erb but the search form is not displaying in my application.

```
   <span style="text-align: right">
    <% form_tag "workout_schedules/find" do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search_string %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search" %> 
    <% end %>
```

Can you please suggest something so that it will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `=` with `form_tag`

```
<%= form_tag "workout_schedules/find" do %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

It will make your search form visible.